# How can I add values from the first column to a new array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
unique_values = (dataset["Label"].value_counts())
    print(unique_values)
```

And this output:

```
BENIGN          1378095
PortScan         158930
FTP-Patator        7938
SSH-Patator        5897
Infiltration         36
Name: Label, dtype: int64
```

How can I add values from the first column to a new array?
The first column should be this: BENIGN, PortScan,..

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: The desired result is an array..Something like: 
array([BENIGN, PortScan, FTP-Patator ,SSH-Patator , Infiltration)

Comment: unique_values
.index.to_list()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this giving you what you want?

```
unique_values.index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform your `index` into a column with `reset_index`

```py
unique_values.reset_index()
```

Output: your initial `pd.DataFrame` with a new column (but no index)